# Webpack can't resolve non-js `require`s from within node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js

I've got a Next.js project configured to resolve imports that end in `.web.js`. This works outside of my node_modules directory. I did this by setting `resolve.extensions = ['.web.js, '.js', '.jsx']` in my webpack config. I understand that this setting is responsible for resolving imports that don't have an extension, e.g. `import _ from './component'`, when `./component.web.js` exists.

I also have some node_modules that make use of this `.web.js` extension. They're private modules, but the idea stands. Let's say our node_modules looks like this. It may be worth noting that these modules have already been transpiled and as such use `require` rather than `import`.

```
- node_modules
  - @foo
    - bar.js
    - baz.web.js
    - baz.native.js
```

Now let's say that we have the following:

```
// bar.js
require("./baz");
```

If I try to import `@foo/bar`, the app will throw a module not found error on the line `require("./baz");` saying that it can't be found. If I change it to `require("./baz.web.js")` or remove the line altogether then the app runs fine.

Why can webpack make these kind of resolutions outside of node_modules, but not within the directory? And how can I tell webpack to resolve those imports, too?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your module resolution strategy, you'll either find some files or not. Node.js resolves modules as outlined [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#node). This means for you that `require('./baz')` is resolved to requesting `/path/to/module/baz.js`. Since your file is not actually named, it is not found. You can use `require('./baz.web')` instead.

As to whether Webpack can "automatically" handle which import to use, it probably comes down to using a plugin or having some sort of logic in `bar.js` to choose between `baz.web` and `baz.native`.